# Getting XML data in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to read XML data in PHP. The XML data is coming from an API whose link is the following: https://seekingalpha.com/api/sa/combined/AAPL.xml 
I just need News Headline, News Link , Published Date and Author Name of the first five news from the API. To do this, I am using the following PHP code:

```
$note = "https://seekingalpha.com/api/sa/combined/".$symbolValue.".xml";
$xml=simplexml_load_file($note);
$jsonArray = array();
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    $newsHeadline = $xml->channel->item[$i]->title->__toString();
    $newsLink = $xml->channel->item[$i]->link->__toString();
    $publishedDate = $xml->channel->item[$i]->pubDate->__toString();
    $authorName = $xml->channel->item[$i]->sa:author_name->__toString();
    $temp = array('Title' => $newsHeadline, 'Link' => $newsLink,'Publish'=>$publishedDate,'Author'=>$authorName);
    array_push($jsonArray,$temp);
}
$jsonNews = json_encode($jsonArray);
$completeData[9] =  $jsonNews;
```

In the above code, $note contains the link to the API. The `$symbolValue` is the value which I am getting from the front end. My code works absolutely until I access the author name ie. The following line of code:

```
$authorName = $xml->channel->item[$i]->sa:author_name->__toString();
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in /home/File/Path
```

It seems like I am not supposed to use the ":" for fetching the author name. 
So, how do I get the user name and put it in the `$temp` such that the Tag for the author name is "Author"?
Please have a look at the API to get an idea about the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

The [`children()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) method supports an argument for the namespace you want to read. This is required when you want to read elements which are not in the current/default namespace.

```
$xmldata = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foobar xmlns:x="http://example.org/">
    <abc>test</abc>
    <x:def>content</x:def>
</foobar>
XML;
$xml = new Simplexmlelement($xmldata);
$other = $xml->children('http://example.org/');
var_dump((string)$other->def);
```

This will output the value `"content"`, but using the expression `$xml->def` will not because that is not in the current/default namespace.

Comment: I didn't give it a try because the first answer worked out for me.Anyway, Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

If you property contains for example a `:`, you could use curly braces

```
->{'sa:author_name'}
```

The values you are looking for are in the `https://seekingalpha.com/api/1.0` namespace.
You could use the [children](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) of the [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) and add te namespace:

```
$authorName = (string)$xml->channel->item[$i]->children('https://seekingalpha.com/api/1.0')->{'author_name'};
```

Or you could use [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php).

```
$authorName = (string)$xml->channel->item[$i]->xpath('sa:author_name')[0];
```

For example:

```
$jsonArray = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $newsHeadline = $xml->channel->item[$i]->title->__toString();
    $newsLink = $xml->channel->item[$i]->link->__toString();
    $publishedDate = $xml->channel->item[$i]->pubDate->__toString();
    $authorName = (string)$xml->channel->item[$i]->xpath('sa:author_name')[0];
    // or xpath
    // $authorName = (string)$xml->channel->item[$i]->children('https://seekingalpha.com/api/1.0')->{'author_name'};
    $temp = array('Title' => $newsHeadline, 'Link' => $newsLink, 'Publish' => $publishedDate, 'Author' => $authorName);
    array_push($jsonArray, $temp);
}

$jsonNews = json_encode($jsonArray);

print_r($jsonArray);
```

Will give you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Title] => Apple acknowledges iPhone X issue in some devices, plans fix
            [Link] => https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/AAPL/news?source=feed_symbol_AAPL
            [Publish] => Fri, 10 Nov 2017 12:04:42 -0500
            [Author] => Brandy Betz
        )
        etc...
```